# Windows 7 keeps blinking screen on restart attempt

Tags: windows-7

I've installed windows 7 ultimate 64 bit on my pc (Intel core 2 duo 3.0 e8400 2gb ram). Normally windows boots up quickly but when I am interacting windows and I press restart button in windows, so after shutting down it keeps blinking screen and not boots up again. So I press power button on *CPU* and start windows again then it boots up fine. I want to know why it isn't boots up on restart attempt? Thanks

Comment: is you are facing this problem only with "windows 7 ultimate 64 bit" ?

Comment: @WaQaRAli Yes I am facing this problem only with Windows 7 64 bit, I haven't tried this on 32 bit version of Windows  , I want to know is there anything wrong with hardware or its bug in windows , I also haven't update my windows yet

Comment: is your system 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: @WaQaRAli Before installation I have checked processor and its 64 bit capable